# Flutter - "Invalid constant value" in nested structures

Tags: flutter, dart

By using [a multilingual approach](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) build is failing with a not fully clear error "Invalid constant value". As for the last screen, AppBar is taking a proper title where as body content is failing. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove "const" keyword on your Center widget as your localized text is not a const value.

Answer (score 2):

Since applocalizations provide values that could change over time within the app, it's not a constant value. So, remove the `const` keyword before `Center` widget. Your updated code would look like so

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.title),
    );
  }
```